# Django: Encryption for Data at Rest?

Tags: django, database, django-models, encryption

I am using Django and am trying to encrypt data at rest in my database which is making use of Django Models.

**What would be the best way of going about this?**

I am aware that there are several libraries for encryption in Django. But, I'm a little spoilt for choice and need some recommendations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django-cryptography` is easy to use and very "dajngo-esque". The only downside might be it hasn't be updated in a couple of years so might have some hidden bugs, but they at least some some industry standards (e.g. salting)

Comment: Oh thanks! I looked into it and it seems like it was updated last year?

https://django-cryptography.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I used nsoftware's encryption library. It costs a bunch of money, but it has worked very well. It is royalty free, but there is no source code.